# Vuejs select box have item selected on load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hey everyone so I have this vueapp that loops through an array of displays it works great except when the app loads up I would like the first display (the one with the array index of 0 or the oldest id) to be placed in the dropdown on load how would I do this? Heres the code.

```
    <div v-show="loggedin==1" class="searchBy">
    <h2>Selected Display</h2>
        <select v-model="selectedDisplay" v-on:change="getVideoAndName()">
      <option v-for="display in displays" :value="display">{{display.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

heres the values in an array item. Keep in mind its an array so it also has an index.

aspectratio:"7:3"
fileFormat:"mp4"
height:"48"
id:"31"
name:"112x48"
shape:"432x184"
shapetext:"Shape 4"
userId:"92"
width:"112"

Answer (score 2):

You can set your selectedDisplay value to displays[0] or however you'd like, so when the select tag is loaded it's default value is set to that, like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedDisplay: null,
    displays: [
      'Vue',
      'React',
      'Angular',
      'Aurelia',
      'Knockout'
    ]
  },
  beforeMount: function () {
    this.selectedDisplay = this.displays[0]
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <select v-model="selectedDisplay">
  
    <option v-for="display in displays" :value="display">{{ display }}</option>
  
  </select>

  <h1>{{ selectedDisplay }}</h1>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with always? If it's about asynchron call, maybe you should put loading or not display the select button at all.

Comment: this will work with your display array however mine has multiple items in the array as shown above. Therefore it doesnt help me